# Yii2 how to create custom validator if list fields is null

Tags: yii2

I have to check if this fields `['approved_groups', 'visits_per_day', 'group_id']` == null, then  `Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', 'error');`

```
 [['approved_groups', 'visits_per_day', 'group_id'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger', 'error');

                return  $this->refresh();
        }, 'on' => self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT],
```

But it is doesn't work

Comment: `when` is used to validate only if certain condition is met 

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation

Comment: but maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont need message as flash, then you can set your own message on error

```
[['approved_groups', 'visits_per_day', 'group_id'], 'required', 'message' => 'Please enter a value for {attribute}.'],
```